# Understanding Django internals working - Where to start?

Tags: python, django

I have dabbled with Django and Created one project successfully.

What I don't understand is how exactly the whole Django Framework Works e.g. internal structure, which line of code gets executed first and why, what would be workflow between a request and response cycle, etc. ? I maybe asking the wrong questions.

What would be the best way to understand the Django framework?

Comment: It's not the best type of question for stack overflow, it's more suitable for some django subreddit

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you to start with a [Django in depth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkwZ1jG3XgA) video by James Bennett. He's member of the Django core team and was involved with it since the 2005. Video descriptions says:

> This is a tutorial that goes beyond most tutorials; it's meant for
> developers who already know a bit about Django and want to really
> understand the inner guts of the framework. This tutorial will *not*
> involve writing code or apps; rather, it'll be a deep tour of the
> workings and APIs of Django itself, across all the bundled components
> and at all levels of the stack.

I personally love this video to death, it's the starting point for my understanding of Django.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for sharing this video. Pretty sure this is overkill for the current question, but it is indeed credible and detailed. (3 hours wow!)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build some more advanced Django projects while being a tyro take a look at these -

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032502.do
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781785886775.do

If you want to read more about Django design patterns and best practices try these
https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8
https://highperformancedjango.com/

Comment: hey, your reply does not answer my question, but Lightweight Django is going to be very useful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're wandering into Django framework territory from the neighbourhood of PHP based server-side scripts.

I too(like any newcomer...) was initially intrigued with the seemingly unnecessary abstractions around webpages, databases and business logic of the websites/web apps.

Firstly, understand that the concept of server-side web development using Django is directed by the MVC paradigm. It takes a while getting used to, but is very simple and intuitive once you get a hang of it.

Next, learn to visualize the app directory and project directory structures and the dependencies between them. For example, you should be able to understand the reason for having a separate **<your_app_name>** folder within every **templates** folder...

Finally, learning by experience and practice is a good way to learn Django basics. Jump into the simple sample implementations of Polls app to get the workflow. Finish all 7 *parts* of the Polls app tutorial.

Don't worry if you don't get concepts at once. Re-read them and don't forget to code as you learn.

Here's the starting point:

> [Django Polls app tutorial Part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Hi Varun, I knew codeigniter 3 when I started learning python and Django. I am past that app. I have read it and understand it. But I wanna know how the framework works internally.

Comment: @ChetanGanji CodeIgnitor... Hello darkness, my old friend... <jokes aside> Oh, I could not gauge the complexity level of the question!  :P Now you've made me curious as well...